# I created button for blinking effect and opacity. While I click the button opacity is working but blink effect is not working

Tags: jquery

I have written the code in jQuery, for opacity and blinking effect. Opacity is working but jQuery is not working.

```
var blinkInterval;
        var pauseInterval;
        var blinking = true;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#flash-toggle").click(function(){
                $('img').css("opacity", "20");
                blinkInterval = setInterval(blink, 500);
                pauseInterval = setInterval(toggleBlink, 2000);
            });

        }) ;     
        function toggleBlink() {
    if (blinking) {
        clearInterval(blinkInterval);
        blinking = false;
    } else {
        blinkInterval = setInterval(blink, 500);
        blinking = true;
    }
}
```

I have added a image using img tag and created button for blinking and opacity effect

```
<img class="bar1" src="flash-red.png" alt="bar" >
  <button id="flash-toggle"   onclick="toggleBlink() ">Enable Blinking</button>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow :) Why would you do this with Timers? Just use CSS and some animation. I can provide an example if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pure CSS Solution would be:

```css
@keyframes blinkingFrames {
    0% {opacity: 1.00;}
    50% {opacity: 0.00;}
    100% {opacity: 1.00;}
}

.blinking {
    animation-name: blinkingFrames;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

button {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
<img class="bar1" src="https://loremflickr.com/300/200" alt="bar" >
<button id="flash-toggle" onclick="$('.bar1').toggleClass('blinking')">
    Toggle Blinking
</button>
```

This make an infinite animation from 100% opacity to 0% and back to 100% as long the element has the class blinking. The animation takes 4s to complete.

Comment: Thank you very much,it's working perfect.How can i do If i add 2 buttons and if i click one button its chane the image as ususal if i select 2 button the image going to change. while i click the 3 button its going to blink like as usal.

Comment: ask a other question. I think this one is solved :)

Comment: haha...i am implementing this one.Ty for your time and patience

Comment: @Royal if you find this to be answering you question, then please mark it as correct answer, so Marcus can get credited for it.